# JavaFX element is initialize with size 0

Tags: css, javafx, fxml

I have a problem when my  FXML are initialized and theirs values are listen by listeners.

So my main window is a `BorderPane`

- TOP =  menu.fxml
- CENTER = center1.fxml
- BOTTOM = footer.fxml

When I click on one of buttons on `center1Controller` the CENTER fxml  should changed to `center2.fxml`.

In `center2.fxml` I have a `Pane` that should be  `Anchor.anchorLeft=60` and  `anchorTop = anchorBottom`

I was created an listener :

```
public void addTopOffsetListener() {

    this.logonWindowPane.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {            
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            double y = (newValue.doubleValue() - logonForm.getHeight()) / 2;
            logonForm.setLayoutY(y);  
        }
    });
}
```

But one my screen is reload the logonForm is in bad place.  When I debug moment the initialization  `getHeight()` returns 0.

It is placed in correct place after resizing window.

I was trying fixed size of this element on FXML and on CSS.

Actually I was find an workaround. When I initialize a screen2Controller a I have added this line

```
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
  this.logonForm.resize(300, 400);
}
```

There is my Screen2 fxml :

```xml
<AnchorPane id="logonWindowPane" fx:id="logonWindowPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="genealogytree.application.fxmlcontrollers.LogonWindowController">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@../styles/application_logon.css" />
    </stylesheets>
   <children>
        <Pane id="logonForm" fx:id="logonForm" prefHeight="400" prefWidth="300" minWidth="300" minHeight="400"   styleClass="projectPane"   AnchorPane.rightAnchor="60.0" />
   </children>  
</AnchorPane>
```

And the FXML of element there I put in logonForm :

```
<Pane styleClass="logonFXForm" prefHeight="400" prefWidth="300" minWidth="300" minHeight="400"     xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="genealogytree.application.fxmlcontrollers.LogonFormController">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@../styles/application_logon.css" />
    </stylesheets>
    <children>
      <JFXPasswordField focusColor="#1f7f6a" layoutX="38.0" layoutY="133.0" maxWidth="224.0" minWidth="224.0" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="224.0" promptText="Password" unFocusColor="#253930">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </JFXPasswordField>
      <JFXTextField focusColor="#1f7f6a" layoutX="38.0" layoutY="54.0" maxWidth="224.0" minWidth="224.0" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="224.0" promptText="Login" unFocusColor="#253930">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </JFXTextField>
      <JFXButton buttonType="RAISED" graphicTextGap="8.0" layoutX="61.0" layoutY="224.0" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="178.0" ripplerFill="#32ae8f" styleClass="jfxButton" text="CONNECT" textAlignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </JFXButton>
      <Hyperlink layoutX="38.0" layoutY="305.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="250.0" text="Do not have an Account ? " />
      <Hyperlink layoutX="38.0" layoutY="340.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="250.0" text="Forgotten Password ? " />

   </children>
</Pane>
```

But there is another method to resolve my problem in FXML or CSS only ?

Comment: You have a properties options in the Scene builder , try using that to open the fxml file and using that to set the pane to the desired location

Comment: this not working, because at moment the initialization it is reset. Actualy in SceneBuilder my pane is on top. And after  initialization  the top of logonForm is on center (verticaly) of LogonWindow (center2).

Comment: Please look at this link http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm

there are inbuild layouts and you can use them 

if this dosn't help Please try and hide and unhide features using setVisible method in your scene .

Comment: No this not help.

Comment: any other ideas ??

Comment: I am not at system, as soon i reach will let you know if i get any